# AWS static links fail without "index.html"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, hugo

I've created a static website (using Hugo) that has links that look like http://www.example.com/post/my-post/. I upload the site to AWS (in an S3 bucket with CloudFront). When I point my browser to that URL, I get an AccessDenied error. But if I tack on "index.html", all is well.

I suspect there's some really obvious bit of config that I'm missing. Apologies, if this is a stupid question, but I couldn't think up an effective google search to find an answer.

Comment: What is the `Index Document` set to under Properties->Static Website Hosting for the S3 Bucket?

Comment: It sounds like you selected the bucket from the drop-down in CloudFront.  That selects the REST endpoint for the bucket, which is what you need for authenticated content delivery... not web hosting.  Get your bucket's web site hosting endpoint hostname from the S3 console, and use that as the origin server hostname in CloudFront.

Comment: You da man, Michael. that fixed it!